# exploding csv data sending them for data retrieval

Tags: php, continuous-integration

I want to explode the list of employee IDs that is stored in *multiId* and use them to retrieve data from the database. And then send emails to corresponding email addresses. Please help me with this.

```
        <?php
function sendmailto($id){
    $this->load->library('email');
    $result = $this->demand_model->get('demand_master', 
        'DEMAND_ID ,COUNTRY, NAME, LOT_NO,BLOCK_VISA_NO, BLOCK_VISA_ISSUE_DATE, PRE_AUTH_DATE, CREATED_DATE', 
        'DEMAND_ID = '.$id, NULL, NULL, true);
    $demand = $this->demand_model->getVacancyForList($id);

    /** 
      $val['id']=json_encode($_POST('multiId'));
      var_dump($val['id']);
      exit();
      */
    $eid = $this->input->post('multiId');

    $mailid = explode(",", $eid);
    //print_r($mailid);
    foreach ($mailid as $eid) {
        var_dump($eid);
        $emaillist['ids'] = $this->demand_model->getEmailbyId($eid);
        var_dump($emaillist['ids']);
    }
    $this->email->message('<html><body>
        <div class="col-md-12 wrapper"><b>Company Name:'
           .$this->demand_model->getCompanyName($result->NAME)
           .'-'.$this->demand_model->getCountryById($result->COUNTRY)
           .'</b></div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-6">Pre Auth Date:'. $result->PRE_AUTH_DATE.'</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">Lot No:'.$result->LOT_NO.'</div>
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>');
    $this->email->subject('This is test email');
    $this->email->to('san_bro18@outlook.com');
    $this->email->send();
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();    
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Error messages? What did you debug, and up until which point all works as expected?

Comment: Can you post what format "multiId" has, or string you want to explode ?

Comment: @Durim multiId:14,17,18,19,20,21,22,23. this multiId has come from the check box

Comment: @tricot the problem is that,by using  this multiId i want to retrieve the email of the person and send them. but i am unable to pass one by one value in the database.so that i can retieve email id

Comment: $mailid = explode(",", $eid); - I see this in your code and this explodes that string. I think it's better to use IN filter in database for this and fetch the records. eg. WHERE id IN (1,2,4,5)

Comment: how to do IN filter @durim

Comment: use paste.org, and paste getEmailbyId function there, so i can see what is happening in that function